# How to Recover Data From OS Flashed Android Phone?

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset, data-recovery

I am Using `Micromax YU Yuphoria` .. Its `rooted` device. suddenly my device get stuck on `Cyanogen Logo` During `Reboot`.

I thought there is no way to get rid out from that. so reflash it with same `cyanogen 12.1 Stock ROM`. But I didnt backup my data so i lost it. is there any way to recover it back?

i tried `Dr.Fone Wondershare`, `Easeus Mobisaver` but nothing works. because those will work on formatted device . but mine OS reflashed one. so i wish to recover my precious data... kindly help me regarding this..  Thanks

Comment: First, if you just flashed (and didn't wipe), no data should be lost. Second, have you already checked with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info), which deals with stuff like that?

Comment: Thanks @lzzy for your response. i didnt wipe. OS got stuck in logo so i simply flashed it using some .bat scripts for windows. thats it.. is this possible to recover my data .

Comment: If it wasn't wiped, it should startup normally with all your data in place. If it doesn't, please check with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) first, as I already recommended.